# В чём необходимость использования addValueEventListener при аутентификации пользователя через firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

В проекте мне встретился код (signin пользователя по почте и паролю firebase):

[image: Код]

Я выкинул большую часть кода и это никак не повлияло на работу приложения:

[image: Код2]

Подскажите пожалуйста, за что отвечала та часть кода которую я выкинул **(databaseReference.addValueEventListener... )**.

Comment: Я полчаса просидел форматируя код - он плыл и плыл. Я отчаялся добавить столь большой фрагмент кода в вопрос, решил картинкой. Простите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Пример вверху имеет дополнительную логику в случае если данные изменятся по текущей ссылке вы сделаете переход на MainActivity. Надо это или нет вам решать.

Сам **ValueEventListener** имеет 2 колбека:

```
onCancelled(DatabaseError error)
```

Туда придет ошибка если с серваком чтот не так или откаблучили по правилам безопасности.

```
onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
```

А этот метод будет вызываться при любом чтение или записи в той области куда введет ссылка, так как я описал в сама начале.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 

Данные не изменяются, но почему тогда метод onDataChange срабатывает в 1-ом случае? Аутентификация работает и в 1-ом и 2-ом случае.

Comment: Возможно при аутентификации тоже тригерится, это уже лучше на примере смотреть